# How can I edit the labels of the X and Y axes in a figure of ggiNEXT?

Tags: r

My question is, **How can I edit the labels of the X and Y axes in a figure of ggiNEXT?**

```
data(spider)
str(spider)
out=iNEXT(spider, q=0, datatype="abundance")
spider_plot=ggiNEXT(out, type=1, facet.var="site", color.var="order")
spider_plot
```

Comment: Have you tried to edit the axis label with ggplot2 conventions like: `spider_plot + labs(x = 'xxx', y = 'yyy')`, where `xxx` and `yyy` are the desired axis-labels.

Answer (score 0):

`ggiNEXT` is a ggplot2 extension of an iNEXT object. Which simply means that after you created the object, you can use ggplot2 commands to manipulate the plot.

```
library(iNEXT)
library(ggplot2)
data(spider)
out <- iNEXT(spider$Girdled, q=0, datatype="abundance")
spider_plot <- ggiNEXT(out, type=1, facet.var="site", color.var="order")

# add ggplot2 adjustments via labs
spider_plot + labs(x = "my x label text", y = "my y label text")
```